# Populating All Activities (including Care Plan Tasks) from Patient view into Care Program Enrollee Timeline view

Tags: health-cloud

Hi All Health Cloud Experts,

I need some help in understanding functional & technical feasibility of the below scenario:

The org that I am working in currently requires that Tasks (including care plan tasks) that populate as part of the Activity Timeline on Patient (Person) Account view to be populated as part of the Activity Timeline of the Care Program Enrollee view  as well. Is this possible to implement?

Since Care Plans are based out of Case Objects and there is an existing Junction object relationship between Patient (Person) Account and Case (Care Plan) objects, its OOTB in SF Health cloud to populate all Care Plan tasks as part of patient view Timeline. But how to populate the same care plan tasks that this patient is enrolled in, into the timeline for the same patient as a Care Program Enrollee?? Care Program Enrollee is a different junction object altogether between Care Program and Patient (Person) Account objects....is there a way to link Care Programs to Care Plans (by establishing object relations) and then create a look up field to populate care plan tasks for the patient into the Care program enrollee Timeline view?

Requesting you to please share your comments and advise!! Thank You!